# Is it possible to change the color of the text according to the background color?

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds

I'd like to automatically change the color of the text according to the background color.

I've used `tikz` to create the background (the shape is only an example) but any other way to do it is welcome.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,\paperheight);
        \coordinate (C) at (\paperwidth,0);
        \fill[blue] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example}
    Could this text be automatically white on blue and blue on white?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Intuitively you'll have to do this manually using clipping.

Comment: I don't know much about clipping in `tikz`.

Comment: +1 nice question! I am sure that PowerPoint can't do this hehe lol

Comment: @manooooh Indeed, it can't. I asked just for that reason :):):)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The idea is simple: use some nontrivial blending mode.

You might want to

- tune the colors, so that "blue" minus "yellow" is "white"
- modify the background, so that the lower right corner looks right.

I test the document with Preview and Adobe Reader on Mac.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,\paperheight);
        \coordinate (C) at (\paperwidth,0);;
        \coordinate (D) at (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill[blue] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
        \fill[white](D) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example}
    \pgfsetblendmode{difference}
    \color{yellow}Could this text be automatically white on blue and blue on white?
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit:

As @Werner suggested, if you do not know how to fix the footline, add this line:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\pgfsetblendmode{normal}}{}
```

Change `footline` to anything else if you find them unexpected.

On the other hand, if you think it is awesome,

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\pgfsetblendmode{difference}}{}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew that some `tikz` expert would have provided a gorgeous solution, thank you!

Comment: The better fix for the navigation symbols is `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}`. I've listened to (and given) lots of beamer talks in my life, but have never seen anyone use these links (except inadvertently).