# How Tikz blending modes are working?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, backgrounds, blend-mode

In short, I would like to do exactly what is done in a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356766/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-the-text-according-to-the-background-color), but for any colors. Or at least understand better how it works.

To be more precise: I would like to automatically change the color of the text according to the background color(which is done in the previous question mentioned).
The answer given, using a blend mode, is a bit "magic" to me: it is working for blue and white.
But I would like to know how to the same for any pair of color (let's say, `colorA` and `colorB`).
I read the documentation about blend modes, but I found no formula or algorithm I could reverse-engineer to reproduce the "magic" answer for any colors (or at least understand how it works).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{255,0,0} % Red for the example but could be any other color
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{0,0,255} % Blue for the example but could be or any other color

% Define colorC and colorD to fit with the blend of colorA and colorB
\colorlet{colorC}{colorA!50!colorB} % 
\colorlet{colorD}{colorB!50!colorA} % or maybe something like R_A + R_B, G_A + G_B, B_A + B_B

\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,\paperheight);
        \coordinate (C) at (\paperwidth,0);
        \coordinate (D) at (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill[colorA] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
        \fill[colorB](D) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example}
    \pgfsetblendmode{difference}% or another blend mode
    \color{colorC} Could this text appear with colorA on a colorB background and with colorB on colorA background?
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well your example works. So what is the problem?

Comment: As far as I know, Ti*k*Z/PGF uses the PDF blend modes. So, if you are looking for a formula, you should look for the defintion in the PDF standard.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes it compiles, but the text color is not switch from blue (colorB) to red (colorA)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Ok thank you for the tip, I will dig in this direction.

Comment: looks ok here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOrNz.png (viewed in acrobat reader)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I have the same. It is purple to me all the line, so it is not switching from blue to red.

Comment: it is changing color, zoom in:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7vjw.png

Comment: I am usure whether it is clear to everybody how the "difference" blend mode works: it "subtracts either the blend color from the base color or the base color from the blend color, depending on which has the greater brightness value" (according to [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/applying-blend-modes.html)). So, it does not change red to blue and blue to red if you place one color over the other, but (at least to my understanding) the overlapping part will be magenta (regardless of which color is on top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not really answer the question (I believe it is impossible with any given colors), but it is a way to achieve the result.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{200,0,0}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{0,0,200}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\fill[transparent!0] (-1.5,-1) -- (-1.5,1) -- (1.5,-1) --cycle;
\node[transparent!100] {\Huge\bf Test};
\clip (-1.5,1) -- (1.5,1) -- (1.5,-1) --cycle;
\node[transparent!0] {\Huge\bf Test};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myinversefading]
\fill[transparent!0] (-1.5,-1) rectangle (1.5,1);
\fill[transparent!100, path fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (-1.5,-1) rectangle (1.5,1);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[colorA, path fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (-1.5,-1) rectangle (1.5,1);
\fill[colorB, path fading=myinversefading, fit fading=false] (-1.5,-1) rectangle (1.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text and background split in two colors]

*Edit:* Can also be made with just one `tikzfadingfrompicture`, if noting else is need in the background

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{200,0,0}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{0,0,200}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\fill[transparent!0] (-1.5,-1) -- (-1.5,1) -- (1.5,-1) --cycle;
\node[transparent!100] {\Huge\bf Test};
\clip (-1.5,1) -- (1.5,1) -- (1.5,-1) --cycle;
\node[transparent!0] {\Huge\bf Test};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[colorA] (-1.5,-1) rectangle (1.5,1);
\fill[colorB, path fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (-1.5,-1) rectangle (1.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or completely without `tikzfadingfrompicture` if the goal is just this one result:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{200,0,0}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{0,0,200}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[colorA] (-1.5,-1) -- (1.5,-1) -- (-1.5,1) --cycle;
\node[colorB] {\Huge\bf Test};
\clip (-1.5,1) -- (1.5,1) -- (1.5,-1) --cycle;
\fill[colorB] (-1.5,1) -- (1.5,1) -- (1.5,-1) --cycle;
\node[colorA] {\Huge\bf Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use `\bf` etc. Those macros have been obsolete in LaTeX for decades and are not supported by all classes.